# How is language specification created

Tags: java, c, compiler-construction

I wanted to ask, what is java written in, but I found an answer to this on stackexchange, which said,  **you don't write language with a language, it's a specification, but the JDK is written in C**.

**Now, my question is**, if the JDK is written in C, is Java basically a different form of the C language, like an extension or something, with more features added? How is  this specification created, and what's the relationship between these three things:

- The tool that interprets the specification(like the JDK)
- The specification itself
- The language the tool was created in.

Comment: Nah, think of the JDK as any other program. You could write it in many different languages. You could even lift the boot by the strap and remake the JDK in Java now.

Comment: Just because the jdk or jvm is written in C doesn't mean there is any relationship between java and C. The java spec is the JLS and any java compiler/runtime environment has to implement that specification

Comment: A JDK can be written in any language that's capable of implementing the JDK specification. C is not a bad choice at all for that.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Though a JVM written in C++ would be somewhat ironic

Comment: You create a language specification by writing the language's syntax and semantics into words (precisely and completely), putting those words into a document and then publishing the document. There might be a committee involved and an approval or even standardization process, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I don't understand all the downvotes here. Sure, the question is a bit naïve, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: you can also ask how is it possible to program the chess game in C as the C language does not know anything about the game rules.

Comment: @mathmaniage: Java and C have little to do with each other from a *language* point of view.  The Java compiler (which translates the Java source text into JVM byte code) and the JVM (which executes the byte code) can be written in almost any language, though C and C++ are probably the most common. For reference, here are the [Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/jls12.pdf) and [Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/jvms12.pdf) specifications.  They're just text documents that describe how the language and JVM should behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding a few things, so let's go to the basics first:

A computer program is nothing more than a set of instructions that are read by the processor and then executed. A list of tasks that are executed one by one.

Java uses something that is called the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). The JRE is sort of (not exactly) a virtual processor, with its own instruction set called java byte code. This 'virtual processor' runs inside of your operating system.

The Java Runtime Environment is written in some language. The Sun JRE is written in C. The C code is in turn compiled into the machine code of your real processor (So code your processor understands).

Java is compiled into java byte code.

So to answer your question: A specification is nothing more than a description of how the java programming language should behave and what it looks like. Basically a regular text document you can write in something like word.

With this specification programmers can build a compiler. A compiler is a program that changes java code like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0)
            continue outer;
    }
    System.out.println (i);
}
```

into bytecode that looks like this

```
0:   iconst_2
1:   istore_1
2:   iload_1
3:   sipush  1000
6:   if_icmpge       44
9:   iconst_2
10:  istore_2
11:  iload_2
12:  iload_1
13:  if_icmpge       31
16:  iload_1
17:  iload_2
18:  irem
19:  ifne    25
22:  goto    38
25:  iinc    2, 1
28:  goto    11
31:  getstatic       #84; // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
34:  iload_1
35:  invokevirtual   #85; // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
38:  iinc    1, 1
41:  goto    2
44:  return
```

The compiler program that does this can be written in any language, however it is recommended to write it into low level languages like C++ to make the compiling process quicker.

Comment: "So to answer your question: A specification is nothing more than a description of how the java programming language should be compiled into its byte code." I disagree. The Java language specification specifies how a Java program should behave. It does say that a Java program should be compiled to .class files, but it does not care *how* this is done or which exact bytecode a given program will compile to. It only cares that the generated bytecode fits the specified behaviour. The JLS does not specify the behaviour in terms of bytecode. It doesn't even describe what Java bytecode looks like.

Comment: @sepp2k That is fair, let me think of a better description and edit my reply

Comment: Suggestion: Change "C/C++" to something like "C++ or some other language". The term "C/C++" is heavily frowned upon here because there is no such thing. They are completely different languages.

Comment: @klutt Okay, done!

Comment: Nice. I don't know if I'm a bit nitpicking now, but it looks like you're saying that a JRE is always written in C++. I can edit if you don't mind?

Comment: A bit nitpicky, but I don't mind. Make your changes on the things you think are unclear and I'll accept them

Comment: ["javac is itself written in java."](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac). Of course, it doesn't have to be. But it is interesting that it is.